# How can I concatenate "this" and an additional string selector using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation, selector

I have the following code:

```
            $("table.altRow tr:visible").each(function (index) {
                if (index % 2) {
                    $(this).addClass("oddColor");
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("evenColor");
                }
            });
```

but I now need to run this code for some tables separately in a loop (you can ignore why I am doing this for this question as my question is more about syntax).  So I want to have something like this:

```
      $("table.altRow").each(function () {
            $(this + " tr:visible").each(function (index) {
                if (index % 2) {
                    $(this).addClass("oddColor");
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("evenColor");
                }
            });
      });
```

the issue with the code above is this line:

```
   $(this + " tr:visible")
```

I am trying to figure out how to write the select that represents that table in the loop, but concatenate the "tr:visible" after it.  What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: "this" is a reference to an object which you are concatenating with a  string.you can use "this" as context in which you want to access "tr:visible". in that case syntax should be $("tr:visible", this);

Comment: i have no idea who downvoted this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
$(this + " tr:visible")
```

to

```
$("tr:visible", this)
```

using context, or simply

```
$(this).find("tr:visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to apply rows style instead of JQuery parsing

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: the above css (nth-child) doesn't work on IE8 and below

Comment: And as the jQuery includes a `:visible` filter, it won't work correctly if some elements are not visible.